# NOOB - confused by plane coordinates

Tags: modeling

I am using Blender in conjunction with a Sweet Home project that was well on the way. I am learning how to create models in Blender but have only just begun. However, my other project requires ceiling light models with light source coordinates where bulbs would be. I have a free source model for my light fitting and imported into Blender. I clicked on the faces within each light bulb holder (3 in total at 120 degrees to each other) and, although these are in different spatial positions, I was confused by the XYZ coordinates for each of these being in the same position. I had made sure it was these 3 separate faces clicked each time. Why would XYZ coordinates (in metres to to 5 decimal places) show as the same XYZ values?

I realise this will just be my misunderstanding but any help gratefully accepted.

Comment: Did you select the faces or the objects which are at the same location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XYZ coordinates, depending on where you're looking, are dependent on the origin of the object, not the individual faces. Better viewed in Object mode than Edit mode. It may be that you have 3 different lights, but only one object, or the origin of all of the lights is at the same location. Sometimes when objects are created in another program an array or copy is used in creating the multiple objects, and the origin remains the same.

Here are two objects with the same origin location (denoted by the orange dot between them), and thus the same XYZ coordinates, even though the objects are in different locations:

[image]

[image]